# What useful function does tap operator bring in RxJs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

What does `tap` operator actually do? What happenes (should happen) when you execute it on a value? Should it just execute some code? If it should just execute some code, then is it just a wrapper for that code?

For example, for does it do below?

```
clickStream$.pipe(
   tap((event) => {
       event.stopPropagation();
       event.preventDefault();
   }),
   debounce(300),
   map((event) => event.key)
).subscribe((key) => console.log('key debounced: ', key))
```

or in this example

```js
export class LoggingInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    console.log('Outgoing request:');
    console.log(req.url);
    return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(event => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
        console.log('Incoming response: ');
        console.log(event.body);
      }
    }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By piping Rxjs operators together we start out with one observable, and end with another observable.

```
const userBooks$ = getUser(emailAddress).pipe(
                     switchMap(user => getBooksForUser(user.id));
```

1. We start out with a method that returns an `Observable<User>`
2. We pipe this to `switchMap` and call another method that returns and `Observable<Book[]>`

This is the functional reactive nature of Rxjs. You pipe together operators to transform streams.

You can think of these as list comprehension methods like map, reduce, filter, merge ... but for asynchronous streams -- not for arrays or lists.

So if all we can do with pipe an `Observalbe<T1>` to operators and get `Observable<T2>` out -- how do we do other things, like call console.log(..) -- or show an error to the user? Or whatever we need to do that interacts **with the world outside the chain of Rxjs operators**. Anything that touches state, calls something, outside of the operators is a side effect.

```
const userBooks$ = getUser(emailAddress).pipe(
                     tap(user => console.log('user id: ', user.id),
                     switchMap(user => getBooksForUser(user.id).pipe(
                       tap(books => console.log('books: ', JSON.stringify(books)));
```

`tap(..)` does not change the transformation of the stream -- it is completely non destructive. For this reason it is often used for debugging, as these can be safely added and removed without affecting the chain of operators.

Comment: should I think of `tap` as an operator which receives `Observable<T1>` and returns `Observable<T1>`?

Comment: Exactly, it pipes through the stream and does not change it.

Answer (score 0):

It's about separating side-effects from pure (mathematical to be more precise) computations. Inspired by functional programming, where side-effects are either impossible at all (and thus such a language is completely useless for a lot of real-world scenarios: for example, you can never query a database or write something to console) or allowed only within some explicit conditions (like the famous `IO` monad in Haskell), rxjs does its best to follow such a way of thinking. Unfortunately, it still lacks razor shape separation line: on the contrary to abovementioned Haskell one **might** introduce a side-effect outside the `tap`: let say, one codes something like `myObservable.pipe(map(x => { console.log(x); return x * x; });` (you can never translate this code to Haskell bypassing `IO` type) - there is side-effect mercilessly mixed up with pure computation. JavaScript is a programming language does not enforce purity at all; yet rxjs tries to provide a useful set of primitives allowing you to introduce side-effects apart from pure code: `myObservable.pipe(tap(console.log), map(x => x * x))`. Now the map is pure with all the benefits of purity and `tap` is a well-defined area of **controlled impurity**. Purity indeed not the central idea of framework, but arguably one of them.

P.S. At this point you might think that a "mathematical computation" is something you've learned at school: multiplying some integers or whatever algebra; that's not quite correct. Don't hesitate to take some time and learn the distinction between pure and impure functions and their applications and consequences to get an adequate understanding of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The `tap` operator is used to introduce **side effects**.
You can think of a **side effect** as something that **happens** **on the side** of your **main action**.

In your example, the `clickStream$`'s observers are **only interested** in receiving notifications whenever click events occur. What happens inside the `tap` operator is a side effect, because, besides emitting click events, you also have other actions like `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`.

Another side effect could be **logging**. Another one would be sending a request to the server when the user submits a form.

Comment: And what about the second example in the question?
Honestly, I see `tap` operator as a code wrapper which holds some code to be executed on an observable's data.

Comment: I'd say it's still a side effect. Your subscriber is only interested in receiving the response. Yes, I believe you can think of it as a code wrapper, but it does **not** influence the main flow of the data. Consider `of(5).pipe(tap(v => v * 10))`; your subscribers will receive `5`.

Comment: It's like you want to go from `A` to `B`, but on your way, you call a friend and tell her how your day went. You(the notification) are not going to be affected by a phone call, because you are still on your way to `B`. (`A` - the producer, `B` - the consumer).

Comment: Your definition of "side-effect" is pretty misleading. -1.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov may you explain why? I'd greatly appreciate it so I could improve my understanding.

Comment: Side-effect is something that does not depend upon explicit dependencies given as an arguments or constants defined in parent scope. It's a piece of action that happens by its own rules and thus introduces new **implicit** dependencies not mentioned by your function definition and may or may not **affect** the whole result of a computation with respect to **implicit yet sometimes even unmanagable** state. There exists much more rigorous defition, but I don't want to bother you with that. See my answer above for some more details.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov thank you. I don't doubt your explanation as my FP knowledge does not go beyond pure functions at a basic level. But I'd argue that in the context of RxJs, my explanation regarding side effects is not misleading. I also tried my best to explain without using too much jargon.

Comment: Side-effects is a core idea of rxhs due to hot observable and guys like `Subject` which mantians a mutable list of subscribers. So side-effects are already there, at the root of implementation. `tap()` exists solely for one purpose: to **message** that "this is a side-effect; step carefully".